# Подключение CSS файлов python django 3.x

Tags: python, django, django-template

Здраствуйте, я новичок, создал приложение в проекте джанго, теперь хочу стилизовать страницы в папке templates, использую наследование шаблонов, также подключил navbar

```html
{% include 'navbar.html' %}
```

к нему тоже хочу прописать стили в navbar.css. Проблема в том, что когда прописываю link в хтмл, то стили применяються ко всему html документу. Можно ли сделать это как-то по-людски, или выход тут один - оборачивать в `div` ?

Буду премного благодарен за помощь!

Comment: так это же стандарт, когда ты подключаешь таблицу стилей, она всегда применяется ко всему документу. Если ты хочешь, что бы она влияла только на navbar, тогда определяй там стили для классов, которые будут использоваться только в твоем `navbar`